# How to get how many times a product was added to cart or Bag from sales_flat_quote_item table?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, quoteitem

I would like to get how many times a single product that was added to cart from sales_flat_quote_item table. Please guide me how do it achieve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

directly on the db:

```
SELECT count(1) from sales_flat_quote_item where product_id = your product id here
```

or via code:

```
$productId = your product id here
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $productId);

$size = $collection->getSize();
```

Comment: also you can filter only active quotes items (i.e. shopping carts), join `sales_flat_quote` and filter by `is_active` = 1